# Passing Python List of Symbol Values to R Legend Call Through rpy2

Tags: python, r, plot, legend, rpy2

I am running into a problem trying to pass a Python list to an R legend call for a plot using rpy2.  I generate a list of text names and their corresponding symbols from an existing dictionary as:

```
    dataDict = {'data':{...},
                'symbols':{'xylem':14,'groundwater':17,'lagoon':16,'stream':15}}
    nameListForLegend = [name for name in dataDict["symbols"]]
    symbolListForLegend = [dataDict['symbols'][category] \
                           for category in dataDict['symbols']]
```

The nameListForLegend variable works in the call, but the symbolListForLegend does not:

```
    r.legend(1.5, -42, nameListForLegend,
             pch = symbolListForLegend,cex=3,col="black",border = 0)
```

I have tried passing it in as an R object with hacky solutions such as:

```
    #after converting each list element to a string
    symbolListString = ",".join(symbolListForLegend)
    symbolListForLegend = robjects.r('list('+symbolListString+')')
```

All return:

```
    RRuntimeError: Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :invalid plotting symbol
```

As is usually the case, I'm missing something simple here.  Any help or direction to appropriate documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`symbolListForLegend` is a Python list, which has no direct conversion to an R object (although it could be an R list with default-named elements). The R function is expecting a vector.

Try:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector
symbolListForLegend = [dataDict['symbols'][category] \
                       for category in dataDict['symbols']
symbolVectorForLegend = IntVector(symbolListForLegend)
r.legend(1.5, -42, nameListForLegend,
         pch = symbolVectorForLegend, cex=3, col="black", border = 0)
```